# с++ Морзянка, открытие файла

Tags: c++

Нужна программа, которая открывает файл и выводит текст на экран через азбуку морзе. Код работает, вот только не преобразует в Морзе 1 символ в тексте. Что не так? Жирным выделил, что вот тут он вызывает 1 символ, но как сделать правильно не знаю

**F>>en;**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char en;
ifstream F;
    F.open(L"C:\\Users\\Андрей\\Desktop\\123.txt");

if (!F.is_open())
    cout << "error";

    F>>en;

    cout<< en <<endl;

while (F >> en)

     switch (en)
    {
    case 'A': case 'a':cout<< ".-.1"; break;
    case 'B': case 'b':cout<< ".-.-.-.-2"; break;
    case 'C': case 'c':cout<< ".-.-.-.-3"; break;
    case 'D': case 'd':cout<< ".-.-.-.-4"; break;
    case 'E': case 'e':cout<< ".-.-.-.-5"; break;
    case 'F': case 'f':cout<< ".-.-.-.-6"; break;
    case 'G': case 'g':cout<< ".-.-.-.-7"; break;
    case 'H': case 'h':cout<< ".-.-.-.-8"; break;
    case 'I': case 'i':cout<< ".-.-.-.-9"; break;
    case 'J': case 'j':cout<< ".-.-.-.-10"; break;
    case 'K': case 'k':cout<< ".-.-.-.-11"; break;
    case 'L': case 'l':cout<< ".-.-.-.-12"; break;
    case 'M': case 'm':cout<< ".-.-.-.-13"; break;
    case 'N': case 'n':cout<< ".-.-.-.-14"; break;
    case 'O': case 'o':cout<< ".-.-.-.-15"; break;
    case 'P': case 'p':cout<< ".-.-.-.-16"; break;
    case 'Q': case 'q':cout<< ".-.-.-.-17"; break;
    case 'R': case 'r':cout<< ".-.-.-.-18"; break;
    case 'S': case 's':cout<< ".-.-.-.-19"; break;
    case 'T': case 't':cout<< ".-.-.-.-20"; break;
    case 'U': case 'u':cout<< ".-.-.-.-21"; break;
    case 'V': case 'v':cout<< ".-.-.-.-22"; break;
    case 'W': case 'w':cout<< ".-.-.-.-23"; break;
    case 'X': case 'x':cout<< ".-.-.-.-24"; break;
    case 'Y': case 'y':cout<< ".-.-.-.-25"; break;
    case 'Z': case 'z':cout<< ".-.-.-.-26"; break;
    } 
    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: Первый символ...

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, поправь код (добавь 4 пробела перед каждой строчкой), а то все очень непонятно.
А во-вторых, если я правильно разобрал твой код, то у тебя первый символ читается и выводится до цикла распознания. Следовательно, он не будет переводиться.
Убери

```
F>>en;
cout<< en <<endl;
```

Comment: Звёздочки - это попытка выделить жирным.

Comment: хехе... Убрал, все отлично работает, спасибо! А звездочки это шрифт жирный, не знаю почему так код скопировался сюда криво.

Comment: Т.е для ifstream не нужна команда cout для вывода на экран?

Comment: Ты на экран выводишь символы. У тебя получалось, что ты считал из ifstream первый символ, вывел его на экран, а только потом в цикле начал так же считывать из ifstream остальные символы, начиная со второго и внутри switch выводить тем же cout-от символы. ifstream ничего не знает про вывод, он только читает. А cout только выводит.

Comment: @Андрей код скопировался правильно. Только когда Вы делали строку жирным, он добавляет ** по обоим бокам. Это тут форматирование в SO так работает. И с коде жирность не работает.